# How can I use C++ to assign variables in JavaScript using Emscripten and keep them in scope?

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I'm trying to do some library testing using emscripten and c++. I need to make some JavaScript variables persist between c++ calls, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

I figure it's either something simple that I'm missing, or it just isn't possible. This is a standalone program with nothing else running. The following is a minimal example:

```
#include <emscripten.h>

int main() {
    //this works and prints 1
    EM_ASM(
        var x = 1;
        console.log(x);
    );
    //this throws an error 'x is not defined'
    EM_ASM(
            console.log(x);
    );
    return 0;
}
```

I compile and run the code using the following commands:

```
emcc main.cpp
node a.out.js
```

The output is correct for the first call, but the second call throws a not defined error. I need some way to keep this variable in scope between calls so I can use it.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the `var` before declaring `x`:

```
#include <emscripten.h>

int main() {
    EM_ASM(
        x = 1;
        console.log(x);
    );
    EM_ASM(
        console.log(x);
    );
    return 0;
}
```

That seems to work with emcc v1.35

**[edit]**

Please see the explanation and much better answer of [Clint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49661577/3931225)

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer will work, you open yourself up to some difficult to track bugs. Using `x = 0` could potentially overwrite any other `x` variables in the scope chain.

A better solution would be to use getter/setter functions:

cpp:

```
EM_ASM(
    var x = 1;
    setX(x);
);
EM_ASM(
    var x = getX();
);
```

js:

```
var x = 0;

function getX() {
    return x;
}

function setX(newX) {
    x = newX;
}
```

Another solution would be to store the value in C++ by returning and inserting it into JS by using `EM_ASM_INT` and `EM_ASM_`. `EM_ASM_INT` returns the return value of the javascript to cpp, while `EM_ASM_` allows you to insert arguments into the javascript using `$0`, `$1`, `$2` etc.

```
int cppX = 0;
int main() {
    int x = EM_ASM_INT({
        var x = 1;
        console.log(x);
        return x;
    });

    cppX = x;

    EM_ASM_({
        var x = $0;
        console.log(x);
    }, cppX);
    return 0;
}
```